# I want to know why this input element is checked but the view is not match

Tags: html

[image]

when i creat a webpage with Vue,something happen,in this picture.

Answer (score 1):

The checked attribute represents the *default*, not the *current*, value.

It doesn't update as the user interacts with the UI.

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible way to reproduce:

```js
document.getElementById("foo").checked = false;
```

```html
<label for="foo">Click me <input id="foo" type="checkbox" checked="checked"></label>
```

Your HTML element has a `checked` property which is usually `true` or `false`. You will need to refer that attribute in order to properly detect the value.